# Can I still make changes to a branch that has already been merged into the master?

Tags: git

A few days ago I merged a `Fix Branch` into the master. Now it turned out that I still have to edit one place. The ProductOwner has expressed the wish in the ticket that has already been closed. Now I wonder if I can check out the old fix-branch and add the missing change and make another `Merge Request` against the master.

My feeling is that it is better to create a new fix branch instead of using the old branch that has already been merged.

Comment: Either way is fine from `git`'s POV.

Comment: @eftshift0 Thanks! and from a team point of view. Can it lead to complications? If I take the old branch I would check it out and decouple it with `git rebase master` so that I can put it at the top of the next commit. If I take the old branch I would check it out and decouple it with `git rebase master` so that I can put it at the top of the next commit. Correct?

Comment: rebase? No, no rebases.... you can just check out the old branch, adjust, commit, then push and create a new PR.....  given that the branch had been already merged (and I assume we are talking about a _real_ merge), then the PR will only include a single commit, the new one we are talking about.

Comment: @eftshift0 ok. i think it was a real PR. What is a real PR?

Comment: Real _merge_? Well... A merge, not a rebase, not a squash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A branch in git is actually just a name for a particular commit, and from there *backwards* though history. So continuing to use a branch just means moving the name to some new commits. That doesn't directly answer your question, but it's important to understanding the following scenarios:

1. You used a "fast-forward merge", pointing master directly to the tip of the feature branch. The two branches are now completely indistinguishable, and adding more commits to the feature branch is just the same as if you had only just created it.
2. You used a "true merge", creating a merge commit with the previous tip of master as one parent, and the tip of the feature branch as a second parent. The difference between the two branches is that master has that merge commit in its history but your feature branch doesn't. If you add more commits to the feature branch and do another true merge, git will understand which commits are new (the ones not already in master's history) and everything will be OK.
3. You performed a "true merge", but resolved conflicts and pushed the result directly to master, without committing them to the feature branch. If you continue the branch and merge again, you might have confusion over those conflicts; to avoid this, merge *from* master *into* the feature branch, so both contain the resolved code.
4. You performed a "squash merge", throwing away all the history from the feature branch, and creating a single commit with all the changes in. In this case, git has *no knowledge at all* of how master and the feature branch are related, and you should *definitely not* reuse the branch, because git will see all of the original commits as "new" (not in master's history) and try to merge them again.

On top of the above, there are some *procedural* reasons why creating a new branch might be helpful:

- Starting from master ensures you are not missing other people's changes as you develop and test
- Creating a new name means you can refer to the two branches separately if you need to untangle something later

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue at all with using a branch that has been merged. I would suggest simply updating the branch to include the merge commit, then continue working from there by rebasing onto (an updated local version of) `master`

```
git fetch origin master:master
git rebase master
```

Then you can `git add` and `git commit` on your branch as usual.